# how do display html + css tags in a rails helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I am trying to write something like this, but it display me the whole string. Not the formatted "Today!". Feel free to tune my method :) thanks

```
def days_left(deadline)
  (if deadline.date-Date.today == 0
    "<strong>Today!</strong>"
  elsif deadline.date-Date.today < 1
    "<div class='expired'>Overdue</div>"
  else
    (deadline.date-Date.today).to_i
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def days_left(deadline)
  (if deadline.date-Date.today == 0
    "<strong>Today!</strong>"
  elsif deadline.date-Date.today < 1
    "<div class='expired'>Overdue</div>"
  end).html_safe
end
```

Or, display it in the view with

```
<%= raw days_left(d) %>
```

Comment: it gives me 'undefined method `html_safe' for (138/1):Rational'

Comment: Replace `.html_safe` with `.class` and double-check that it's a String. Rails3 monkey-patches `String` and adds an `html_safe` attribute. You could also just try `.to_s.html_safe` because it appears your actual code is returning a Ruby Standard Library `Rational` class number and not a `String`.

Comment: I should note that the parens around the `if..end` are entirely optional, it's OK to just say `end.html_safe` if you like that better.