# Element created in helper method is displayed with html visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following helper method in `application_helper.rb`

```
content_tag :span, "some text"
```

The rendered page is displaying "`<span>some text</span>`"

I've tried running it through the methods [`raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) and [`html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) but that doesn't change anything.

Inserting the `content_tag` above directly in the view displays it correctly.

How do I escape the HTML when creating an element with a helper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<%= raw helper_method %>
```

[how do display html + css tags in a rails helper method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741690/how-do-display-html-css-tags-in-a-rails-helper-method)

Here's api

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw